# Make Ctrl+Alt+L show login screen

Tags: login

I've been messing with some things and the lock screen is not working well at the moment. Since I like the standard login screen much better anyway, I would like to change the action for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut. At the moment, it does the same thing as "Lock Screen" in the top-right power/settings menu. I would like it to instead have the same effect as "Switch User Account" on the user menu.

How can I do this?

FYI, I'm using 12.04 with the classic Gnome session. Things might look somewhat different in Unity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is possible. Here is the procedure.

Open up settings and go to keyboard->shortcuts->system and unbind the `Lock Screen` shortcut. (Make sure it says `disabled` where the key combo normally is)

Go to `Custom shortcuts` on the same tab and create a new shortcut named `login screen`. In the command field enter the following:

```
gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.DisplayManager --object-path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0 --method org.freedesktop.DisplayManager.Seat.SwitchToGreeter
```

Set the keybinding to Ctrl+Alt+L and then you are all done. From now on when you press that key combo you will be placed on the login screen.

Comment: Thanks! I had some clashing shortcuts with IntelliJ IDEA that I managed to clear off at the OS level :)

Comment: This works perfectly well in Ubuntu and Kubuntu distros, but is there any way to make something similar work in Fedora too?
In fact, it'd be way better if there was a common command to do the same on Ubuntu as well as Fedora.