# Resume to login screen after suspend

Tags: suspend, login-screen

I have managed to change keyboard shortcuts to use the login screen instead of the lock screen, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178187/make-ctrlaltl-show-login-screen). However, after I suspend the computer and wake it up again, I get the lock screen.

How can I resume to the login screen after suspend? This is on 12.04, classic gnome session.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. You can manage scripts which are run after/before suspend/hibernation (`etc/pm/sleep.d/`). To make your computer load login screen (just before) suspend/hibernation just do the following:

Execute these commands in terminal:

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/99-login-screen.sh
gksu gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/99-login-screen.sh
```

Paste this into file:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend)
        gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.DisplayManager --object-path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0 --method org.freedesktop.DisplayManager.Seat.SwitchToGreeter
    ;;
esac
exit $?
```

and save it. Now try to suspend and resume your system :) [I tested it on ubuntu 12.04.02 LTS]

Comment: If you use **00** instead off 99, to run it first of all, it will be neater.